# Does anyone know where the backlight fuse is on a 2016 MacBook Pro 15" touchstrip model?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I found an image of a 13" but it doesn't match the 15" board.  It is a Model A1707.  Just need to test the fuse.  Thanks!